# Using discord.py to send a message everyday at a specified time

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Discord bot that will send a message at a channel at a given time, I found previous codes but they don't seem to work for me since they give indention errors.

I'm not an experienced programmer and any answer would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to look for `AsyncIOScheduler`, from the `apscheduler` module. If you are using a class based bot, the code below should work:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
from discord.ext.commands import Bot as BotBase


class Bot(BotBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=your_command)
        self.scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

    async def on_ready(self):
        self.scheduler.add_job(self.birthday, CronTrigger(hour=0))
        self.scheduler.start()

    async def action(self):
        channel = self.get_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send('Your message')
```

The scheduler will execute the `action` method every time the hours counter of the `CronTrigger` reaches 0.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not familiar with classes yet. Although I did manage to get a loop working now, this time I want to run it in a different thread.